# mysql count zeros in sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I got mysql database and I need to get number of zeros in sequence and print them all with date from first zero, so for example I got a table like this

```
id, date, impuls_count
1, '12-05-15 12:00:00', 60
2, '12-05-15 12:01:00', 0
3, '12-05-15 12:02:00', 0
4, '12-05-15 12:03:00', 49
5, '12-05-15 12:04:00', 0
6, '12-05-15 12:05:00', 0
7, '12-05-15 12:06:00', 0
8, '12-05-15 12:07:00', 0
9, '12-05-15 12:08:00', 30
10, '12-05-15 12:09:00', 0
```

this should give the result like this:

```
'12-05-15 12:01:00', 2
'12-05-15 12:04:00', 4
'12-05-15 12:09:00', 1
```

I tried to solve it on my own but my query works very slow(I got 5000 rows in a table) and it sometimes prints same row twice

```
SELECT qwe.date, ile
    FROM (SELECT  p.date,
         (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM performance_v2
                WHERE date > p.date
                AND date <
                    (SELECT MIN(date)
                    FROM performance_v2
                        WHERE date > p.date AND impuls_count > 0)) ile
          FROM performance_v2 p
              WHERE p.impuls_count > 0
              AND (date(p.date)
                BETWEEN  '2015-05-08%'
                AND  '2015-05-08%')
                AND (time(p.date)
        between '14:00:00' and '22:00:00')
    ORDER BY 1) qwe
WHERE ile > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, this is easiest to solve using variables.  The idea is to have a counter increment each time the value of `impuls_count` changes.  This defines groups of common values.  You can then filter the values and aggregate to get what you want:

```
select min(date), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (@g := if(@ic = impuls_count, @g,
                       if(@ic := impuls_count, @g + 1, @g + 1)
                      )
             ) as grp
      from table t cross join
           (select @ic := 0, @g := 0)
      order by id
     ) t
where impuls_count = 0
group by grp
```